# Select Operator in the Contentful SDK

Tags: contentful

How can I use the Contentful Select Operator in the Javascript SDK, to only select the property: fields?

The GET request in the documentation looks like this

```
GET https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/<space-id>/entries/?select=fields
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const contentful = require('contentful')

const client = contentful.createClient({
  space: '<space_id>',
  accessToken: '<content_delivery_api_key>'
})

client.getEntries({
  content_type: '<content_type_id>',
  select: 'sys.id,fields.<field_name>'
})
.then((response) => console.log(response.items))
.catch(console.error)
```